Cannot suggest tag synonym [ng-modules] for [angular-module] because it allegedly already exists, but it doesn't
I want to mark ng-modules as a synonym for the angular-module tag. When I open the tag detail page, enter ng-modules in the synonym input field and click Suggest, I'm getting the following error:
Failed to propose synonym:

A synonym from ng-modules to angular-module exists, chains are not allowed

This is strange because I have searched in the existing tag synonyms but couldn't find those tags in the synonyms, not even in the pending approval ones which was the cause for a similar tag synonym creation issue.
Why am I unable to create this tag synonym?

It seems like it's the same as the question you linked. There's a pending suggested synonym from [tag:angular-module] to [tag:angularjs-module]

You are right, thanks. I couldn't find this synonym suggestion, because I have an insufficient tag score for the angularjs-module tag. It's not really clear to me why I cannot vote on this suggestion because I actually have a score of 5 or higher on the angular-module tag, but that's a different question.

I myself don't have enough tag score for either of those tags to vote for synonyms (although actually the synonym page shows the suggested synonym regardless if you open it for the target tag), I just ran a SEDE query to check.

Wow this tag synonym suggestion is open for over 10 years with a score of 0. Back then Angular 2 has not even existed yet. I think this suggestion should be removed by the mods.
